# how to show remote branches of a specific remote

Tags: git, git-bash

I have three repositories with different names under one folder:

```
remote1/branch1
remote1/branch2
remote2/branch1
remote3/branch1
```

When I want to get the remote branches, I want to do specific remote branches from just one of the repositories, I know that `git branch -r` shows me all of them but I am wondering how to do git branch -r on only one mentioned repository?

I was trying `git branch -r=remote1` or `git branch --remotes=remote1`

However this is not correct, wondering if there is a way to do it?

I have only one directory, inside that directory I have different remote 
repositories.

here is more information:

```
$ git remote -v
remote1   https://url/rep1.git (fetch)
remote1   https://url/rep1.git (push)
remote2   https://url/rep2.git (fetch)
remote2   https://url/rep2.git (push)
remote3   https://url/rep3.git (fetch)
remote3   https://url/rep3.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick approach could be to use `grep` after your git command like this:

```
git branch --remote | grep rep2
```